# Elasticsearch - Error in bulk indexing - this IndexWriter is closed

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

We are indexing documents into elasticsearch from a java application.
We are unable to index all the required docs as indexing fails for some of them due to following exception(found from log)

```
org.elasticsearch.index.engine.CreateFailedEngineException: [investigations][0] Create failed for [Event#jEbSeiQASEemf6xTHSaUZw]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.create(InternalEngine.java:397)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.create(InternalIndexShard.java:382)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardIndexOperation(TransportShardBulkAction.java:401)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:153)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:556)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:426)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: this IndexWriter is closed
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.ensureOpen(IndexWriter.java:645)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.ensureOpen(IndexWriter.java:659)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1525)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1199)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.innerCreate(InternalEngine.java:462)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.create(InternalEngine.java:384)
```

What could be the issue? This happens even if the number of documents being indexed is as low as 28 and none of them is too big in size.

Comment: Hi, what version of Elasticsearch are you using? What library are you using to index your documents?

Comment: Elasticsearch version is 1.0.1. We are using ES Bulk API to index the docs

Comment: had this issue in 1.1.0 with the index name "shipped_events_v0001_2014_april".  changed index name to "events_v0001_2014_april" and it started working.  changed back, it failed again.  so i guess its the long index name or something?